# Grails GORM One To Many Issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 2 domain models

```
class Project {
    static hasMany = [quotes:Quote]
}

class Quote {

}
```

Question:

When I delete the Project, I need to remove all the quotes associated to that project. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

In your Quote class I would add:

```
static belongsTo = [project: Project]
```